# HAProxy not detecting backend with non-standard http port

Tags: haproxy, selinux

I have a HAProxy setup where the backend server is running a webserver non standard port.The config is as follows

```
global

    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3
    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    stats enable
    stats auth someuser:somepassword
    stats uri /hpstats
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option http-server-close
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend  http-in
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/test.pem no-sslv3

    #define hosts
    acl host_demo       hdr(host)       -i testing.domain.com

    #usage rules
    use_backend demo    if      host_demo
    default_backend             demo

backend demo
    server      demo 192.168.XX.XX:4873 check verify none
```

With this setup HAProxy always complained with the following error.

```
Message from syslogd@localhost at Nov  2 12:31:58 ...
 haproxy[24266]: backend demo has no server available!
```

When I changed the backend server to port `80` from `4873` everything works fine

```
backend demo
    server      demo 192.168.XX.XX:80 check verify none
```

I am running Centos 7 on both machines. I have tried to enable the `http_t_port` using `semanage` on both machines but that didn't have any effect. Only when I changed the port from `4873` on the server to `80` or `443` that the HAProxy load balancing worked and it stopped complaining.

Can anyone point out why is that and how should I resolve it so that I can run the HTTP on non-standard port?I am pretty sure I am missing setting somewhere considering I am using SELinux.

Comment: This is because there is probably no service listening on port 4873.
So the health check fails, and HAProxy considers the server as down.

Comment: There is a service listening. I can go to `192.168.XX.XX:4873` in the browser directly and it works but `testing.domain.com` returns 503 which is ofcourse because HAProxy thinks that the server is down. I even tried adding `tcp_check` to add a custom check for port `4873` in the `backend` configuration but that didn't work either.

Comment: If you suspect sellinux, check the audit log and/or use semanage to switch haproxy_t to permissive.

Answer (score 0):

@andthereitgoes

It seems that the service is not listening on the port 4873 or its being blocked by iptables at source or destination.

Comment: There is a service listening because I can go to 192.168.XX.XX:4873 in the browser directly and it works.